# Mocking HTTP calls when using the ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dojo, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm an AngularJS developer, so most of my unit tests that rely on HTTP use the `$http` service and the mock `$httpBackend` service.

I'm integrating some code with the ArcGIS JavaScript API, which makes HTTP calls, but obviously doesn't use `$http`, so my mock backend isn't going to help me isolate my unit tests.

For example, when I construct a `WMSLayer` object...

```
require(['esri/layers/WMSLayer'], function(WMSLayer) {
  var layer = new WMSLayer('/mock-endpoint');
});
```

it's going to try to make a real HTTP connection to the mock endpoint.  Is there an easy way to mock this out so it doesn't do that and instead goes to a fake backend?

Some ideas that I've come up with:

- I know that internally the ArcGIS API uses Dojo. I'm not as familiar with Dojo -- is there  an equivalent to `$httpBackend`?
- I'm using Jasmine as my unit test runner. I could possibly replace the Ajax calls with my own.
- I could potentially do something with the `proxyUrl` settings to bounce back requests, but then I'm getting into some server side code and I'd like to keep things mostly client side.

Answer (score 1):

I develop dojo apps and my favorite way is using a 3rd part lib [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/).

In particular I use the fake XMLHttpRequest of fake server - http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server

So in short I don't know of a native way of doing this in dojo but I've found SinonJS a great library for this (and other mocking/stubbing) and it's easy to integrate with most testing frameworks.

Good luck!

Comment: I've never head of that, but it looks pretty cool.  I actually wound up going a different route with our ArcGIS integration, but I'm going to check this out.